# How to write the result of a query to a file in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from employee" queryout "C:\bcptest2.txt" -T 
-SDemo -Usa -PPassword1 -c -t'
```

when i ran the above  command to create a file and store the records from `employee` table in the file but i got the **error** as

```
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
Unable to open BCP host data-file NULL
```

-- Test 2

```
DECLARE @querytextNoVid VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @querytext VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @filelocation VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(255)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#data2') is not null
begin
drop table #data2
END
CREATE TABLE #data2(name varchar(100),addres varchar(100))
insert into #data2 select 'Manas','pratap'
insert into #data2 select 'Ranga','Sasi'
select * from #data2 
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from #data2" queryout "C:\test\bcptest2.csv" -T -Sdemo -Usa -PPassword1 -c -t'
```

When i run the above script i got the error like

NULL
Starting copy...
SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#data2'.
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to resolve column level collations
NULL
BCP copy out failed
NULL

--Any help on the above error

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to article [Unable to open BCP host data-file SQL Server error](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/unable-to-open-bcp-host-data-file.aspx)

You are required to grant write permissions to SQL Server service user NT Service\MSSQLSERVER on the file folder

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using Database name in your query, that's why the error.

you have your **SELECT** statement like this:

```
select * from DatabaseName.SchemaName.employee
```

Or, you have to provide an argument to specify the database name like:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from employee" queryout "C:\bcptest2.txt" -d "DatabaseName" -T -SDemo -Usa -PPassword1 -c -t'
```